# When calculating Parry, if Fighting is untrained, do I add +1 or +2?

Tags: savage-worlds

Parry is a stat calculated from 2 + half of the character's Fighting die. For untrained skills, a character would roll d4-2. Is this -2 taken into consideration when calculating Parry?

Answer (score 9):

### Add +0

Parry is 2 + half Fighting skill.
If Fighting is untrained then the fighting skill is 0, though like all Untrained Skill rolls you'd roll d4-2 when you make a Fighting roll.

A character with untrained Fighting has Parry 2. Incidentally, this is the same as the Parry of an inanimate object, like a brick wall.

This is in the rule book, **Chapter One: Character Creation**, under **Traits**. For the then-current *Savage Worlds Deluxe* rules, that's on page 17.

> Parry is equal to 2 plus half your character’s Fighting (**2 if a character does not have Fighting**), plus any bonuses for shields or certain weapons. This is the Target Number (TN) to hit your hero in hand-to-hand combat.

For the now-current *Savage Worlds Adventure Edition*, that's on page 10, in even more explicit language.

> **Parry** is equal to 2 plus half your character’s Fighting die type (a total of 2 if a character doesn’t have Fighting), plus any bonuses for shields or certain weapons.

Comment: Your quote actually reads, to me, as if you'd add 2 for Fighting. The parenthetical seems to refer to "half your character's Fighting", not the total.

Comment: @AndruC Then you're reading it incorrectly. Because it is meant to say "Your Parry is 2 if Fighting is untrained", as clarified repeatedly in the PEG forums Official Answers.

Answer (score 4):

The Parry score is only calculated from the fighting dice, not from the fighting skill. If you are untrained in fighting, then your *skill* is d4-2, but your fighting *dice* is actually non-existent.

Therefore if you are untrained in fighting, your parry is half of nothing (0) + 2 = 2.